# How to unzip Minecraft PI edition through terminal

Tags: raspbian, linux, minecraft

I recently got the Raspberry Pi Model B, and have been tinkering with it for hours on end. I recently discovered that one of my favorite games, [Minecraft](http://pi.minecraft.net/) is now available. I downloaded the program and saved it to my Desktop. I then looked at the instructions. Here is my terminal session:

```
cd Desktop
```

This changed the directory to Desktop - no biggie.

```
tar -zxvf minecraft-pi-0.1.1.tar.gz
```

This is where problems arise. Here are the error messages:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

First off, can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? Then, if at all possible, *please* explain to me what the globbity-gloop on the screen is; I need to *cognate*, not simply nod my head and copy your work.

Thanks so much - I know that I will weather the [perfect storm!](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/5599/6609)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are doing it correctly. My guess is that the file is incomplete. That's what "unexpected end of file" means- basically `tar` is saying "I expect the file to continue but it stopped".

Often sites will list a `md5sum` or other hash you can use to verify a download. This one doesn't. I downloaded the file locally to get the size- 573922 bytes. So, do the following:

```
ls -l minecraft-pi-0.1.1.tar.gz
```

What size is listed? Assuming it's wrong, you can remove the file:

```
rm minecraft-pi-0.1.1.tar.gz
```

And then download it again:

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.minecraft.net/pi/minecraft-pi-0.1.1.tar.gz
```

Verify the size (with `ls -l`) and then use the `tar` command you have above.

To reiterate, here are the three lines `tar` returned and what they mean:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
```

"I was trying to uncompress the file and it wasn't complete"

```
tar: Child returned status 1
```

"I am the `tar` command, I asked `gzip` to uncompress the file, and it failed with a code.`

```
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

"I don't know what to do with these errors. I'm outta here."

Comment: Yes, I think that it wasn't a complete download. How can I have Midori notify me when the download is complete?

Comment: You should try downloading the file using wget ... that's what I used.

Comment: If the download is incomplete, you'll have problems on using it. There's no reason for a modal box or getting more complicated unless you are in a production environment. (you could script to ensure the hash matches, but.. why bother?)

Comment: @HeatfanJohn I tried to download the file using `wget`, and I typed the URL in correctly. Sadly, the download failed. The error was `wget: unable to resolve host address 's3.amazonaws.com'` HELP!

Comment: Actually I got `ERROR: The certificate of 's3.amazonaws.com' is not trusted.` on my Windows machine running Cgywin.  I was able to download the file using `HTTP://` instead of `HTTPS://`.  Can you `nslookup` s3.amazonaws.com` on your machine?  Maybe try downloading the file on another computer and then transferring the file to your PI.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to just `sudo apt-get minecraft-pi` but I guess you want to do it this way?
Anyway, it is probably incomplete, shown by this here:

`gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file`
`tar: Child returned status 1`
This pretty much means gzip(which it **uses** to unzip, hence the 'child' part) returned an error code (1). Things won't say stuff like this otherwise most of the time
`tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now` This means `tar` doesn't know what status 1 is (because it isn't gzip)